# Heroku: Getting a "django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(20)" error while migrating in django

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-migrations, heroku-postgres

Everything works fine when i try to migrate on my local server but when i try to migrate on heroku it give me this DataError. Here's the traceback. Also i'm a beginner in django so i'm unable to understand this error.

```
Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, mrpash, sessions
Running migrations:
Applying mrpash.0002_auto_20181108_1931...Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute 
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) psycopg2.DataError: value too long for type character varying(20)


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
  execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 203, in handle
fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 84, in database_forwards
field,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 435, in add_field
self.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 133, in execute
cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
 django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(20)
```

I don't know which field is causing this error

Comment: Somewhere you have explicitly told Django that your field can be max of 20 characters. Check your model deceleration for any field that constrict to 20 characters?

Comment: Thanks man ... It worked

Comment: Hi. I am getting the same error but value 100. I did have some at max_length 100 which I changed but I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [@kstuillich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6771714/kstullich), I did set a max_length of 20 chars in my model. Error got solved after removing the limit.

Answer (score 1):

Search for changes in any fields containing `max_length=20` as the error suggests `varying(20)` which means previously the max_length was more.

1. Increase the `max_length` to greater than any data
2. Delete the last migration file then create new `makemigrations`
3. Finally `migrate`.